# Does exhaust smoke always acompany engine burning oil?

Tags: oil, leak, rebuild

Car(civic vti) is currently loosing a lot of engine oil.  I've already put 4 liters in over a few months\maybe 1000k miles.  Mechanics cannot find any leaks but they couldn't see smoke coming out of the exhaust either.

If you have internal leaks i.e. the oil is being burnt will this always be accompanied by exhaust smoke or can it occur without exhaust smoke in which case, should I accept that my engine is burning oil and I need a rebuild since no external leaks have been identified?

Would there be other ways to diagnose that my piston rings or valves are causing the burning, would a compression test help?

Comment: A compression test won't tell you if it's burning oil. Remember, there are three ring lands on most pistons. The top two lands hold compression rings. The bottom one holds a set of two oil control rings and a spacer to keep them apart. It's the oil control rings which, well, controls the oil. You can still have good compression even if the oil control rings are not doing their job.

Comment: Not sure what your mechanics have tested, but some oil burning/leaks are only apparent under specific circumstances. Worn valve stems/seals will usually smoke on deceleration under load. That said, if oil is going out the tailpipe somehow there will be evidence of it at the exhaust tip, it will be greasy, not just sooty. You can also have leaks that only occur under specific circumstances, look around the engine bay and underneath to signs of oil. 4 quarts in 1000 miles is a lot, IMO.